# AWS Lambda unable to trigger new instance for concurrent operations, runs out of memory

Tags: lambda, aws-lambda

I am using lambda to extract image from a video and upload to s3 bucket. I have given 1028MB memory to the function and it works fine when we upload a single video but when we upload multiple videos multiple lambda is getting executed on same instance because of which the memory used exceeds the Set Memory limit and hence, lambda is failing.

Any solution where Lambda will spin different instance for every trigger ?

Comment: How is your lambda getting triggered?

Comment: I have done s3 trigger as whenever a file getting added in s3 bucket it triggers the lambda

Comment: @MukulMunjal Without code it is hard to tell. But it sounds like you are managing your memory sub-optimal. For example: you can easily process 20 videos, each 500MB with just 128MB of memory. The thing is: you need to manage your memory. Only load into memory what is actually being processed. It sounds like you are doing the opposite: load everything into memory and/or not removing it properly from memory. Again: hard to tell without code.

Comment: okay so the question is how can I make sure on every trigger lambda runs on different instance